# how can i create Quiz app using django framework?

Tags: python, html, django, web, foreign-keys

I am trying to make a quiz app which randomly ask 5 quetions.Before that I used a forein key in models.I go through a django document.Now I want to render all quetions and its 4 option on same page.while going through document it creates a link for each quetion which render on only one quetion using its id. Now if if i render on same page it do not separate radio busttons for each quetion. Link of reference:https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial01/
 my code is given below:

**models.py**

```
class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text

    def was_published_recently(self):
        return self.pub_date >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)


class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.choice_text
```

**views.py**

```
def index(request):
    latest_question_list = Question.objects.all()
    context = {'latest_question_list': latest_question_list}
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)

def detail(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    return render(request, 'detail.html', {'question': question})

def results(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    return render(request, 'results.html', {'question': question})


def vote(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    try:
        selected_choice = question.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
    except (KeyError, Choice.DoesNotExist):
        # Redisplay the question voting form.
        return render(request, 'detail.html', {
            'question': question,
            'error_message': "You didn't select a choice.",
        })
    else:
        selected_choice.votes += 1
        selected_choice.save()
        # Always return an HttpResponseRedirect after successfully dealing
        # with POST data. This prevents data from being posted twice if a
        # user hits the Back button.
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('app1:results', args=(question.id,)))
```

**index.html** Here it createquetion link

```
{% if latest_question_list %}
    <ul>
    {% for question in latest_question_list %}

        <li><a href="{% url 'app1:detail' question.id %}">{{ question.question_text }}</a></li>

    {% endfor %}

    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>No polls are available.</p>
{% endif %}
```

**detail.html** after clicking on quetion it comes on this page where this signle quetion with ans is shown

```
<h1>{{ question.question_text }}</h1>
{% if error_message %}<p><strong>{{ error_message }}</strong></p>{% endif %}

<form action="{% url 'app1:vote' question.id %}" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{% for choice in question.choice_set.all %}
    <input type="radio" name="choice" id="choice{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ choice.id }}">
    <label for="choice{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ choice.choice_text }}</label><br>
{% endfor %}
<input type="submit" value="Vote">
</form>
```

Comment: you can put all radio in the same form but put only one radio button to change the name to choice 1 choice2 and so on and then check the answer for all question in the server

Comment: i am bigginer..can you help me out how can i do it

Answer (score 1):

when you press the submit it send all input data as paramters to post so if you put all input in one form it going to send al of them. and you can figure with one the data refer to by the name you can call the first input 1 and the second 2 and so on and in the server side you should check all the input and if the answer ok you may also use js to send what ever you went